# limit of a (system) function

Tags: limits, continuity

Sorry if my title doesn't explain very well. (I don't know how should I translate it). But I have this problem:
I had this function: 
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{$x$ $\neq$ 0} \\
0 & \text{$x$ = 0}
\end{cases}
$$
Can anyone help me why $$\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = 1$$ and not `0`?

Comment: The name is "piecewise (defined) function", if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0,x\in\mathbb R^*}f (x)=1$$ because
$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R^*)\;\;f (x)=1$$
and we write
$$\lim_{x\to0,x\ne0}f (x)=1$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to0,x\in\mathbb R}f (x) $$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because, when calculating the limit of a function as $x$ tends to a certain value $V$, the point where $x=V$ is not included. 
Since $f(x)=1$ everywhere except $x=0$, and here $V=0$, this just means that the limit must be $1$.

Comment: But what about 0 if $x = 0$ condition? It confuses me. The function is 1 if $x$ if not 0 but it is 0 if $x = 0$.

Comment: Your function says the opposite. Your function says it is $0$ if $x=0$ and $1$ otherwise, and the $\lim_{x\to0}$ only uses $x\ne0$

Comment: I mistyped earlier in my comment and I modify it now. So, (0 if $x = 0$) doesn't make any changes (should not be considered) in the limits of the function?

Comment: Since we are talking about $x$ *approaching* $0$, we are talking about what happens *before* $x=0$ **not** *when* $x=0$